# Using a Buefy component outside of Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, buefy

How can I create a [Buefy notification](https://buefy.org/documentation/notification) outside of a Vue component? For example, I have the following axios interceptor defined with an attempted use of a Buefy notification:

```js
import axios from "axios";
import { Notification } from "buefy/dist/components/notification";

axios.interceptors.response.use(
  response => {
    if (response.data.flash) {
      Notification.open(response.data.flash);
    }
    return response;
  },
  error => {
    if (error.response) {
      Notification.open(error.response.data.flash);
      return Promise.reject(error.response);
    }
  }
);

export default axios;
```

Which leads to this error in console:

> [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler (Promise/async): "TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, figured out the answer shortly after posting this. Leaving the question up with the answer just in case anyone else runs into the issue. Apparently, `import { Notification } from "buefy/dist/components/notification"` was an old way to import, and instead should be imported like this:

`import { NotificationProgrammatic as Notification } from "buefy";`